# Unable to start container. Error message: Open Compute System failed

Tags: docker, dockerfile, azure-web-app-service, containers, docker-for-windows

I am new to the containers and have created a Windows Docker image which is running fine locally as **https://localhost** but when I published the image on Docker Hub and tried to use in Web App Container its failing with the error message: **Unable to start container. Error message: Open Compute System failed.**

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019
ARG source
WORKDIR /inetpub/wwwroot

SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop';"]

RUN Install-WindowsFeature NET-Framework-45-ASPNET ; "\
    Install-WindowsFeature Web-Asp-Net45; \
    Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Uri "https://dotnetbinaries.blob.core.windows.net/servicemonitor/2.0.1.6/ServiceMonitor.exe" -OutFile "C:\ServiceMonitor.exe"

#Expose port 443 to allow incoming traffic over the default HTTPS port
EXPOSE 443

#create a folder on the container to hold the code
RUN powershell -Command \
New-Item -Path sampleaspnet -ItemType Directory

#Set the newly created folder in docker as the working directory for subsequent commands
WORKDIR 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sampleaspnet'

#Copy everything from where you are on host to the working directory in docker (this folder should contain your SSL cert)
COPY ./bin/Release/PublishOutput/ .
COPY IIS_Docker.pfx .

RUN powershell.exe -Command "\
Import-Module IISAdministration; \
Import-Module WebAdministration; \
Remove-Website -Name 'Default Web Site'; \
New-Website -Name 'sampleaspnet' -IPAddress '*' -Port 443 -PhysicalPath 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sampleaspnet' -ApplicationPool '.NET v4.5' -Ssl -SslFlags 0; \
#If you have a password on your SSL Cert, put it here as it needs "secured". If not, remove this line and the argument below it; \
$pwd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String 'admin123456' -Force -AsPlainText; \
#Import the certificate and store it in a variable to bind to later; \
$cert = Import-PfxCertificate -Exportable -FilePath 'IIS_Docker.pfx' -CertStoreLocation cert:\localMachine\My -Password $pwd; \
#Take the imported certificate and bind it to all traffic toward port 443 (you need to specify IP if you want multiple apps on 1 docker which I believe is ill-advised); \
New-Item -Path IIS:\SslBindings\0.0.0.0!443 -value $cert;"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the container logs but an *Open Compute System Failed* is could indicate a problem retrieving and running your image. There is a timeout for loading the image and mounting the backend storage.

Your docker file is doing a lot that's unnecessary though. Your base image is a [cached image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-custom-container?pivots=container-windows#supported-parent-images), which is good because that means images aren't being pulled from fresh. But mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:4.8 [already](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-framework-aspnet) has IIS, .NET 4.5 (through .NET 4.8), and IIS extensibility. You don't need to expose 443 because the app service will bind a port on your image to route HTTP traffic as necessary. You also don't need to configure a SSL certificate as you'll [configure that on the app service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate) as well.

Have a look at this [Dockerfile](https://github.com/microsoft/dotnet-framework-docker/blob/master/samples/aspnetapp/Dockerfile) for how you can configure your image with your .NETFX application but I would start with the following:

EDIT: Here's my complete dockerfile.

```
# image for building our app
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8 AS build
WORKDIR /app

# copy the project files
COPY *.sln .
COPY DemoForms.Web/*.csproj ./DemoForms.Web/
COPY DemoForms.Web/*.config ./DemoForms.Web/
RUN nuget restore

# build it
COPY DemoForms.Web/. ./DemoForms.Web/
WORKDIR /app/DemoForms.Web
RUN msbuild /p:Configuration=Debug

# and run it
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019 as runtime
WORKDIR /inetpub/wwwroot
COPY --from=build /app/DemoForms.Web/. ./
```

Comment: Thanks, Ryan...I will try and update you. Also, can I use this image (mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore/iis) instead of aspnet:4.8 as its size is almost half.

Comment: You can use whatever image you want. It’s just advisable to use an image that’s cached because pulling those images doesn’t require any network retrieval which could, based on image size, result in an timeout.

Comment: I used your Dockerfile which is again working fine locally but failing on Azure with the following error message (including the previous one):

01/11/2020 17:29:45.310 ERROR - Site: abc0111 - Unable to start container. Error message: Docker API responded with status code=InternalServerError, response={"message":"container 644b5135b4cb05e19cb959795e255b48d7bfeca47c1b5f3034b41a398cf06d44 encountered an error during hcsshim::System::Start: context deadline exceeded"}

Comment: @JSK let me try to repo. Is your image on docker hub or ASC? Your project is it .NETFX asp.net project? If yes, web forms or MVC?

Comment: It's a public Docker image with the sampleaspnet5 and a asp.net web form project.

Comment: @JSK I didn’t see sampleaspnet5 listed on https://mcrflowprodcentralus.data.mcr.microsoft.com/mcrprod/dotnet/framework/samples?P1=1604263230&P2=1&P3=1&P4=nW%2BmVFah%2F2fBmcQGAXFT8wsj8cKSDM%2FsEyxcmWHNr0c%3D&se=2020-11-01T20%3A40%3A30Z&sig=AiYyXDU0UFUqTEhIpzouYTMCktFaIloTrT3p%2FTs5wzg%3D&sp=r&sr=b&sv=2015-02-21. What base image are you using?

Comment: Sorry Ryan for the misunderstanding...its my container on Docker Hub. The base image I am using is "mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019". I just copied your Dockerfile and ran it and it worked fine locally.

Comment: Just a sanity check, does mcr.microsoft.com/azure-app-service/samples/aspnethelloworld:latest from the private registry tab load correctly?

Comment: sanity test passed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223990/discussion-between-ryan-hill-msft-and-jsk).